# Summing up the values in the 5th line of every 6-line record in a file

Tags: text-processing

I have a txt file with blocks of text like this:

```
17-01-2023
Purchase AAA
Apple Pay John Doe
Full Payment
-11,34€
0,11€
30-01-2023
Purchase BBB
Mastercard Jane Doe
Installment
-23,90€
0,24€
```

So, we have in sequence, the date, the kind of purchase, the type of payment and name, the kind of payment, the value as negative and the discount.

These repeat through the file with thousands of entries.

I want to sum the values, in this example, 11,34 + 23,90 and get the total as positive. Remember that there is an euro symbol after the number and that in my locale the comma is the decimal separator.

How do I do that from terminal, using say sed, awk, etc.?

Comment: I would to this with a Python script, running from terminal.  More precisely you can use pandas.dataframe.  It has functions to read (read_csv) and manipulate tabular data in various ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the transaction amount is always in the 5th line of a record, a record start is indicated by a date in "DD-MM-YYYY" format, and that this pattern can only ever occur at start-of-record, the following `awk` program will do:

```
awk -v dpt=$(locale decimal_point) '/^([[:digit:]]{2}-){2}[[:digit:]]{4}$/{line_of_rec=0}
     {if (++line_of_rec==5) { if (dpt==".") sub(/,/,"."); total-=$0 } }
     END{printf "Total payments: %.2f\n",total}' input.txt
```

It works as follows:

- It passes the result of the command `locale decimal_point` as variable `dpt` to the program. This is relevant because you seem to be using `awk` in a setting where the the input is formatted using `,` as decimal separator, but the locale is set to something that uses `.`, causing `awk` to miss the decimal part of the number.
- It identifies start-of-record lines by their pattern (we assume no leading and trailing space!), and set a variable `line_of_record` to 0.
- For every line, increase the `line_of_record` counter. If it reaches 5, it will replace the `,` by a `.` (if necessary) so that `awk` interprets the line content as decimal number, and subtract the line content from a variable `total` so as to sum positive payment values.
- At end-of-line, it will print the total.

This is more code than minimally necessary, but makes the program a little more robust if there ever should be empty lines *separating records* (it still relies on the transaction amount to be in the 5th line of a record).

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk - unlike the case on a non-numeric currency symbol prefix like `€-23,90`, a non-numeric suffix will be ignored during numeric conversion. Just be aware that different implementations may handle the locale's decimal separator differently, ex.

```
mawk 'NR%6 == 5 {sum -= $0} END {print sum}' file
```

respects `LC_NUMERIC` / `LC_ALL` as required for [POSIX compliance](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/awk.html), whereas GNU awk deviates from the POSIX specification by default and needs to be instructed to use your locale:

```
gawk --use-lc-numeric 'NR%6 == 5 {sum -= $0} END {print sum}' file
```

See the GNU Awk User's Guide at [Locales Can Influence Conversion](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locale-influences-conversions)

---

Testing with the de_DE.UTF-8 locale for example:

```
$ export LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
$ 
$ mawk 'NR%6 == 5 {sum -= $0} END {print sum}' yourfile
35,24
$ 
$ gawk --use-lc-numeric 'NR%6 == 5 {sum -= $0} END {print sum}' sum=x yourfile
35,24
```

and on Mac OS:

```
$ awk --version
awk version 20200816

$ export LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8

$ awk 'NR%6 == 5 {sum -= $0} END {print sum}' yourfile
35,24
```

Comment: I do not have gawk or mawk in my system but after testing this with awk, the result appears to not include the first line and not showing the decimal part. I think it is related to the fact that comma is the decimal separator in the file.

Comment: @Duck Yes it is - your locale is set incorrectly for using `,`s as the decimal separator. Either set your locale to one that uses `,` as the decimal separator or change the `,`s to `.`s in your input (can be done within the script or before it runs).

Comment: in my country, comma is the decimal separator.

Comment: What it is in your country doesn't affect what it is on your computer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61911355/1745001 might give you some ideas on a locale setting that'd do what you want. That that answer is talking about the thousands separator, not the decimal separator but it's the same idea.

Comment: GNU `awk` respects the locale's decimal radix character if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment. So using `POSIX_CORRECT=1 awk ...` to avoid having to assume any awk implementation. Note that busybox doesn't honour the locale's radix character either.

Answer (score 2):

This one just for fun - assumes GNU sed for the `n~m` construct:

```
$ sed -n '5~6{y/-,€/_.+/;p}' file | dc -e0 -f- -e_1\*p
35.24
```

(of course you can add another sed or tr to convert the decimal point back to the original locale's `,` if desired).

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Without type-checking:*

```
~$ raku -ne 'state $sum1; $sum1 += $_.trans("," => ".").subst(/\€/) if ++$ % 6 == 5; END say $sum1;'  file

#OR 

raku -e 'my $sum1 += $_.trans("," => ".").subst(/\€/) if ++$ % 6 == 5 for lines; say $sum1;'  file
```

*With type-checking:*

```
~$ raku -ne 'state Rat $sum1; $sum1 += $_.trans("," => ".").subst(/\€/) if ++$ % 6 == 5; END say $sum1;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my Rat $sum1 += $_.trans("," => ".").subst(/\€/) if ++$ % 6 == 5 for lines; say $sum1;'  file
```

Briefly (first example), Raku is run at the command line with the `-ne` non-autoprinting flags. A scalar variable `$sum1` is `state`d, meaning it will instantiate before the loop directed by the `-ne` flags commences. In the second statement, if an anonymous incrementing line-counter variable `++$` when `%` modulo divided by 6 equals 5, `trans`late the `,` comma to `.` dot and remove (`subst` with nothing) the `€` Euro sign. Then `+=` accumulate into the `$sum` variable. At the `END` of the loop, `say $sum1`.

Sample Input:

```
17-01-2023
Purchase AAA
Apple Pay John Doe
Full Payment
-11,34€
0,11€
30-01-2023
Purchase BBB
Mastercard Jane Doe
Installment
-23,90€
0,24€
```

Sample Output:

```
-35.24
```

For an accumulating total, just `say` the accumulating variable:

```
~$ raku -ne 'state $sum1; say $sum1 += $_.trans("," => ".").subst(/\€/) if ++$ % 6 == 5;'
```

Sample Output:

```
-11.34
-35.24
```

Inspired by @AdminBee's `awk` answer, you can tolerate blank lines between records if you increment the line-counter only when lines contain `.chars` characters:

```
~$ raku -ne 'state Rat $sum1; say $sum1 += $_.trans("," => ".").subst(/\€/) if .chars && ++$ % 6 == 5;'
```

Sample Output (same as above using either `&&` or `and`):

```
-11.34
-35.24
```

Note, the numbers given in the OP's example are typed as `Rat`ional numbers by default in Raku (other types available in Raku include `Num`s and `Int`s). `Rat`s in Raku (assuming they're small enough) generally don't suffer from rounding errors, and are quickly converted to fractions. For example, change the `END` statement as follows:

```
~$ raku -ne 'state $sum1; $sum1 += $_.trans("," => ".").subst(/\€/) if ++$ % 6 == 5; END say $sum1.numerator, "/", $sum1.denominator;'
```

Sample Output:

```
-881/25
```

For faster manipulation, `say $sum1.nude` returns `(-881 25)`.

https://docs.raku.org/language/numerics.html#Rational
https://raku.org